# Eliminar filas y columnas de una matriz, tomando en cuanta sus elementos

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

tengo que crear un programa que elimine filas y columnas

el programa tiene que analiza todos los elementos de una columna y si todos son 0, esa columna y su correspondiente fila  se elimina

por ejemplo si todos los elementos de la columna 6 son 0, la columna 6 y la fila 6 son eliminadas

primero el programa pide al usuario las dimensiones de la matriz y luego sus valores

```
import numpy
from numpy import delete
m = int(input("Dimension de la matriz:")) 
matriz_v = numpy.zeros((m,m)) 
print ("Introducir los elementos de la matriz") 
for f in range(0,m):
    for c in range(0,m):
        matriz_v[(f),(c)] = (input("Elemento ["+str(f+1)+","+str(c+1)+"] "))
print (matriz_v)
```

por ejemplo, todos lo elementos de la columna 4,5,6 son 0

[image: y lo que quiero una matriz con las filas y columnas]

y quiero esta donde las filas y columnas 4,5,6 son eliminadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy intentando con esta idea, sumar todos los elemento de la columna y si la suma es igual a 0, esta se elimina, (ya que para mi caso de estudio la única forma de que la suma de todos los términos de de una columna sea 0, es si todos los términos son 0)

```
for x in range(0,m): 
    suma_columna = 0
    for y in range(0,m):
        suma_columna = suma_columna +  matriz_v[y][x]
        if (suma_columna == 0):
            matriz_v_c = delete(matriz_v, [x], axis=1)
            matriz_v_c_f = delete(matriz_v_c, [x], axis=0)
```

pero  solo se me elimina 1 fila y 1 columna y no todas que nesecito

gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `matriz_v_c` y `matriz_v_c_f` se reddefinen por cada ciclo del primer for, esto causa que al final solo se aplique el resultado de la última iteración.

Se puede hacer de esta forma pero es complicarse la vida sin necesidad, recurda que **NumPy** y **Python** hacen 'magia':

- Primero buscamos una manera de crear un array de boleanos en el que cada elemento será `True` si esa columna es buena (tiene algún elemento que no sea 0) y `False` en caso contrario. En tu ejemplo el array sería:

  ```
  [ True  True  True  True False False False]
  ```
- Despues aplicamos slicing sobre la matriz original usando ese array de voleanos. Si, resulta que Numpy permite hacer cosas como:

  ```
  >>> import numpy as np
  >>> m = np.array([[1,2,3],
                   [4,5,6]])
  >>> filtro = np.array([True, False, True])
  >>> m[:, filtro]
  array([[1, 3],
         [4, 6]])
  ```

**En tu caso el codigo sería simplemente:**

```
good_cols = numpy.any(matriz_v.T != 0,  axis = 1)
matriz_v = matriz_v[:, good_cols][good_cols, :]
```

Se usa `numpy.any` que retorna `True` en cuanto algún elemento de la columna no es 0 (Short-circuit evaluation), lo que aumenta la eficiencia sobre `sum` o `all`.

Por si se quiere reproducir el código con tu ejemplo:

```
matriz = [[0.003,     0,     0,     -1,     0,    0,    0], 
          [    0, 0.004,     0,     -1,     0,    0,    0],
          [    0,     0,     0.1,   -1,     0,    0,    0],
          [    1,     1,     1,      0,     0,    0,    0], 
          [    0,     0,     0,      0,     0,    0,    0],
          [    0,     0,     0,      0,     0,    0,    0],
          [    0,     0,     0,      1,     0,    0,    0]]



matriz_v = numpy.array(matriz)
good_cols = numpy.any(matriz_v.T != 0,  axis = 1)
matriz_v = matriz_v[:, good_cols][good_cols, :]
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> [[ 0.003  0.     0.    -1.   ]
>  [ 0.     0.004  0.    -1.   ]
>  [ 0.     0.     0.1   -1.   ]
>  [ 1.     1.     1.     0.   ]]
> ```

Comment: me sirvió muchas gracias te lo agradesco